# Macro taking code statement as argument fails when std::map is present

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c-preprocessor, visual-studio-macros

I have a macro used around a code statement, to introduce nested exception handling:

```
#define TRAP_EXCEPTION(statement) \
    try \
    { \
        try{statement} \
        catch(Engine::Exception& e) \
        { \
            throw MyException(e.message()); \
        } \
    }
```

This has been working well until one case raised compiler errors. I managed to construct a minimal example:

```
TRAP_EXCEPTION
(
 std::map<MyType, bool> Map;
)
catch(MyException& e)
{
}
```

This gives the following errors... how do I fix it (ideally in the macro)?

```
> error C2143: syntax error : missing '>' before '}'
> error C2976: 'std::map' : too few template arguments
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

Comment: Look at the preprocessed code to see what the macro expands to (there's an option in VS to generate it).

Comment: Don't use a macro like that.  There are [far better ways to implement exception boundaries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/01/16/exception-boundaries.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure which part of that is applicable here? Can you write a full answer?

Comment: The macro in your question is used to wrap arbitrary blocks of code in a try block.  That article discusses several alternatives to your macro that are much, much cleaner (more maintainable, actually possible to debug through correctly, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros don't understand the template parameters (the angle brackets to be precise), they just see the `,` and think you provided two different parameters to the macro. You need to add round brackets:

```
TRAP_EXCEPTION
(
    (std::map<MyType, bool> Map;)
)
```

and the macro needs to be changed:

```
#define UNWRAP(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define TRAP_EXCEPTION(statement) \
    try \
    { \
        try{UNWRAP statement} \
        catch(Engine::Exception& e) \
        { \
            throw MyException(e.message()); \
        } \
    }
```

Note that this would require you to always provide an additional pair of round brackets on the call side.

In your case (since the macro is supposed to take only one statement), you could also use a variadic macro:

```
#define TRAP_EXCEPTION(...) \
    try \
    { \
        try{ __VA_ARGS__ } \
        catch(Engine::Exception& e) \
        { \
            throw MyException(e.message()); \
        } \
    }
```

which is probably better since the call side doesn't change and

```
TRAP_EXCEPTION
(
    std::map<MyType, bool> Map;
)
```

will now work correctly.

Comment: The first method won't work, since you can't put parentheses around a declaration.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, I forgot that you need the `UNWRAP`-trick to get around that. Fixed the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor doesn't recognise `<` and `>` as brackets, so interprets the comma as a macro argument separator. You'd have the same problem if the statement contained an unbracketed comma for any other reason (e.g. a comma operator, or commas to separate declarators).

If you really want to abuse the preprocessor like this, you could bodge it to accept any number of macro arguments:

```
#define TRAP_EXCEPTION(...) \
try \
{ \
    try{__VA_ARGS__} \
    catch(Engine::Exception& e) \
    { \
        throw MyException(e.message()); \
    } \
}
```

but I would advise you not to try to do anything clever with macros.

Comment: It's not really abuse... this is very similar to something GoogleTest does https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Exception_Assertions I haven't established how their code handles this yet...

Comment: Hmm, GTest also fails to compile when `map` is used :(

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `__VA_ARGS__` trick, you can also use a typedef before the macro.
The `__VA_ARGS__` trick has some drawbacks.

```
typedef std::map<MyType, bool> MyMap;

TRAP_EXCEPTION(
  MyMap Map;
)
```